# Is a fragment added by FragmentTransaction always accessible?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a quick question.

If I add a Fragment by:

> getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(...)

will it be always accessible by:

> getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(...)

assuming I will never call `beginTransaction().remove` ?

(I will only use `hide()` and `show()` transactions to manipulate its visibility)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not , according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)) , it will be accessible , **however** make sure you don't call `.replace()` either.
Because `.replace()` is a like a sequence of `.remove().add()`

Also transactions do not get added to the back stack by default. You can:

```
transition.addToBackStack("TAG");
```

After that you can use its identifier without problem, if you want to refer to it later.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Fragment is always accessible as long as it is attached to the activity. Fragment gets detached as soon as **onDetach** is called.

**onDetach** Called when the fragment is no longer attached to its activity. This is called after **onDestroy()**, except in the cases where the fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation (see **setRetainInstance(boolean)**), in which case it is called after **onStop()**.

For visibility, you are using hide() and show(),

**hide()** and **show()** is only relevant for fragments which are already attached to activity.

In short, **onDetach** never gets called during hide() and show().A attached fragment never get detached from the activity during hide() and show().So ,it will be accessible.